# Selenium Webdriver, How to fix this NullPointer exception?

Tags: java, selenium, nullpointerexception, selenium-chromedriver

Thanks for the quick help! Somewhere I read that I could create an empty array this way. Sorry for the real basic question!

I am trying to make a List of elements that I can sort through later, but whenever I create the list I get a nullPointer exception.

```
List<WebElement> tempList = null;
tempList.addAll(driver.findElements(By.className("result-item")));
```

The HTML page definately has multiple elements with the provided class name, so I'm totally confused. I also get the same exception if I change the code to

```
tempList.add(driver.findElement(By.className("result-item")));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set `tempList` to `null` and then try to invoke a method on the (not existing) referenced object (because the reference points to `null`).

Try the following:

```java
List<WebElement> tempList = new List<>();
tempList.addAll(driver.findElements(By.className("result-item")));
```